# How to make the prefix and captured characters optional in Regex?

Tags: regex

Given following string,

```
var str = "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'project/theme-one', media: 'all' if @auth.show?  %>"
```

Below regex returns a valid match,

```
str.match(/\<%= stylesheet_link_tag\s+['"]?(.*)['"],.+if(.*)%\>/)

// [
//  "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'project/theme-one', media: 'all' if @auth.show?  %>", 
//  "project/theme-one", 
//  " @auth.show?  "
// ]
```

However, it fails with following string (without the if-condition):

```
var str = "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'project/theme-one', media: 'all' %>"

// Expected result
// [
//  "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'project/theme-one', media: 'all' if @auth.show?  %>", 
//  "project/theme-one", 
//  " "
// ]
```

How do I make`if(.*)` part of the regex optional?

Comment: * is for 0 or more, which I think is what "optional" means in this context `(if.*)*`

Comment: @m0skit0 nope, it gives `["<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'project/theme-one', media: 'all' if @auth.show?  %>", "project/theme-one", undefined, undefined]`

Comment: It does match in my test. Do you mean grouping is now different? You didn't ask about grouping.

Comment: Like [`<%= stylesheet_link_tag\s+['"]?(.*?)['"],.+?(?:if(.*))?%>`](https://regex101.com/r/eS4tR7/2)?

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95445

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated the question for the expected result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to make some pattern optional (i.e. matching 1 or 0 times) you need to use a `?` quantifier. If you have a single symbol, a `?` can be appended after it. If you have a sequence of subpatterns, the best way is to place them into a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and add a `?` after it.

You can use

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag\s+['"]?(.*?)['"],.+?(?:if(.*))?%>
                                  ^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS4tR7/2)

An *important point* here is that the first `.+` was too greedy, and ate up the optional `(?:if(.*))?` part. The `.+` should be turned lazy with `+?`. Also, to optimize the pattern a bit, you need to also use the lazy dot matching in between `['"]?` and `['"]`.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /<%= stylesheet_link_tag\s+['"]?(.*?)['"],.+?(?:if(.*))?%>/g; 
var str = '<%= stylesheet_link_tag \'project/theme-one\', media: \'all\' if @auth.show?  %>\n<%= stylesheet_link_tag \'project/theme-one\', media: \'all\' %>';

var res0 = [];
 var res1 = [];
 var res2 = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
 res0.push(m[0]);
 res1.push(m[1]);
 res2.push(m[2]);
}
console.log(res0);
console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(if.*)*` should work fine. Full regex: `\<%= stylesheet_link_tag\s+['"]?(.*)['"],.+(if(.*))*%\>`.

[Test](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95445)